# Редактирование на Spring

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, rest

Как редактировать таблицу в самом таблице на spring, то есть по клику на ячейку

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/479286/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю: вы хотите отредактировать таблицу из БД через JavaScript и HTML. Могу предложить такой вариант:

1. Создаёте table через HTML (или динамически через JS)
2. Отправляете GET-запрос (через XMLHttpRequest или fetch) на сервер через JavaScript, для получения данных из БД (к примеру, через Spring Data или JPA). Отправляете в качестве JSON-объектов ячейки таблицы со значениями
3. Парсите json через json.parse в JavaScript и строите динамически на основе этих данных новую таблицу
4. Устанавливаете обработчики на нужные элементы